# How to replace values for a certain attribute in Neo4j with a csv file

Tags: neo4j, kettle, neo4j-apoc

Hi right now I have a model in Neo4j DB like this:
Person{ID, Name, Age, Major, Department}

Now I'd like to replace Major with Marjor_Text column in a csv file.

May I use Kettle or Neo4j to realize it?
If I'm using Neo4j, I have this script:
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS test
SET Person.Marjor = test.Marjor_text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first have to match the Person

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS test
MATCH (Person:Person{id:test.ID})
SET Person.Marjor = test.Marjor_text
```

Comment: Thank you! with this script, we are going to keep all the relationships with node Person, is that right?

Comment: Yes, Exactly that